# Run pygame app at startup in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: python, startup, mate, ubuntu-mate

I'm trying to make a **digital frame software** with **pygame** and **python**, and want the app to **run at the startup of the machine** when you can see the taskbar and the system is ready to load windows.

I've tried nearly **6 ways** of doing this during the last week, but none worked. I am already tired, and I would like someone to tell me how should I do it.

So.... **HOW DO I DO THAT!!!!!????**

Comment: Please edit and describe what those 6 ways were, what were the expected results and what happened instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create desktop-file for this application (or its script) and then copy this desktop-file to `~/.config/autostart/`.

Or directly

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart/
cat <<EOF > ~/.config/autostart/pygame.desktop # copy from this line to EOF, then paste
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/pygame/frame # or python /path/to/pygame/frame
Name=PyGame Python Frame
EOF
```

Or using GUI tools like Startup Applications - `gnome-session-properties` in GNOME or `mate-session-properties` in MATE.

Then reboot.

Comment: I'm sorry to have already somehow found the solution 1 minute after I made the question and you wrote this very long thing, I'm really sorry. The thing is that I was SOOO dumb to take a look at the control center of the OS, and see that THERE WAS A OPTION CALLED "APPS AT STARTUP"!!! I just entered "python3 [PATH]" and it goddamly worked!!! Again thanks a lot.

Comment: You can always can accept above answer if it helped @JMIDEV.